# Get NuGet package with related Source (Visual Code)

Tags: typescript, github, visual-studio-code, nuget

Hello people outside there,

I am working on a function (in Typescript) with the goal to list all NuGet packages inside my GitHub Repository with their reference sources.

So, in the end it should look like this:

- Package1, version: v1.1.2, source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
- Package2, version: v2.3.1, source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
- package3, version: v1.2.2, source https://otherSource

First I declared this function to collect all available .NET sources I have:

```
export function getDotnetSourcesSync(): string[] {
  const { execSync } = require('child_process');
  const stdout = execSync('dotnet nuget list source --format short').toString();

  // Parse the output and extract the enabled source URLs
  const sources = stdout.split('\r\n')
    .map((source: string) => source.trim())
    .filter((source: string) => source && !source.startsWith('---') && !source.startsWith('Source') && source.startsWith('E '))
    .map((source: string) => source.substring(2));

  return sources;
}
```

Next I wrote a function to find and collect all .csproj-files.

And then I wanted to combine the output of function1 and function2 in this method:

```
async function getAllNuGetPackages(projectList: string[], sourceList: string[]): Promise<{ intern: AllNugetPackageInfo[], extern: AllNugetPackageInfo[] }> {
  const allPackages: AllNugetPackageInfo[] = [];

  for (const project of projectList) {
    for (const source of sourceList) {
      const output = child_process.execSync(`dotnet list ${project} package --source ${source}`);
      const lines = output.toString().split('\n');
      let name: string = '';
      let currentVersion: string = '';
      for (const line of lines) {
        if (line.includes('Project')) {
        } else if (line.includes('>')) {
          const parts = line.split(/ +/);
          name = parts[2];
          currentVersion = parts[3];
          allPackages.push({ project, source, name, currentVersion });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const internPackages: AllNugetPackageInfo[] = [];
  const externPackages: AllNugetPackageInfo[] = [];


  allPackages.forEach((packageInfo) => {
    const isInternal = sources.some(source => packageInfo.source.includes(source));
    if (isInternal) {
      internPackages.push(packageInfo);
    } else {
      externPackages.push(packageInfo);
    }
  })


  return { intern: internPackages, extern: externPackages };
}
```

--> Intern describes all sources from the other source, the rest, which is not 'otherSource' is to be an extern NuGet package

The problem is, that it does not seperate the packages. Either everything is declared as internal or as external with the same source, although package3 comes from a different source.

I found this source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/powershell-reference?source=recommendations but I do not know how to use the **Find-package-command**, it gives me an error (because it cannot access *otherSource* without credential permission)

Is there an easy way to get the corresponding package-source for a NuGet package?
The other option I tried was via the **dotnet nuget list ${project} package --source ${source} - way, but that only works with the **--outdated** option, right?

I hope someone (had the the same problem, solved it and/or) can help me